# Powershell - Comparing and overriding a folder

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a powershell script to compare 1 folder to another, say Folder A to Folder B. I want my script to make folder B look exactly like Folder A every time this script runs. Overriding anything in there, and deleting anything in Folder B that is not in Folder A. I have no code for it yet, and everything ive tried does not work. I made a script that copies from Folder A to Folder B and it works but wont delete anything different and wont override a file. So if its already in there, it doesn't care that the item in Folder A is newer, it will keep Folder B old file:

Test-Path "C:\Users\Shawn\Desktop\Scripts\New Folder"

```
if((Test-Path True))
{
    Copy-Item -Path "C:\Users\Shawn\Pictures\" -Destination "C:\Users\Shawn\Desktop\Scripts\New Folder" -recurse
}

else

{
    New-Item -Path "C:\Users\Shawn\Desktop\Scripts\New Folder" -ItemType directory
    Copy-Item -Path "C:\Users\Shawn\Pictures\" -Destination "C:\Users\Shawn\Desktop\Scripts\New Folder" -recurse
}
```

Comment: How about starting with `Remove-Item "C:\Users\Shawn\Desktop\Scripts\New Folder" -Force` so it deletes the destination, and then just makes a copy of the source? Or are you trying to limit the copies to only what is not already there?

Comment: Why not just `robocopy /MIR` ? You can even add /COPYALL for good measure (if you want to mirror ACLs).

Comment: Using Remove-Item would work, I dont care if it deletes all the data before copying. Also how does /Copyall work? Mirroring the ACLs would be good to. Ultimately this is going to be used to copy a users Recent Items on his PC locally, and then copy the shortcuts to a server. That way when he is working from home he can see what his recent items here at the office were. Right now if the user navigates to \\PCName\C$\Users\Name\RecentItems it shows up blank unless he is physically on his PC.